# Solving long trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve the following trigonometric equation of two variables?

```
Solve[
  1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] + 
  4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 θ] + 
  8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[θ] Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[y]) == -3 && 
  0 < y < 2*Pi && 0 < θ < 2*Pi, 
  {y, θ}]
```

Comment: (1) You have one equation, so you can expect to solve for only one unknown. (2) This gets you part-way there: `Solve[TrigExpand[
   1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] + 
       4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 θ] + 
       8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[θ] Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[
         y]) == -3] /. {Sin[θ]^2 -> 
    1 - Cos[θ]^2}, {θ}]`

Comment: You can solve for `y` thus: `sols = {y -> 2 ArcTan[v, w]} /. 
  Solve[TrigExpand[1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] + 4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 θ] + 8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[θ] Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[ y]) == -3] && v^2 + w^2 == 1 /. {Sin[y/2] -> w, Cos[y/2] -> v}, {v, w}, Reals]` -- You get 16 solutions in terms of `θ`, each defined over a different domain. Seems somewhat unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot` shows you possible solutions

```
ContourPlot[1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] + 4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[y]) ==-3
, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, FrameLabel -> {y, \[Theta]}]
```

[image]

The solution follows

```
sol[y_?NumericQ] :=NSolve[{1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] +4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[\[Theta]]Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[y]) == -3
, 0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 Pi}, {\[Theta]}]
```

for example

```
sol[2]
(*{{\[Theta] -> -2.45038}, {\[Theta] -> 2.45038}}*)
```

plot

```
Plot[\[Theta] /. sol[y], {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I get a table of solutions each of which increases by 0.01?

Comment: You're welcome: `Table[{y,\[Theta] /. sol[y]}, {y, 0, 2 Pi,.01}]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `// TrigExpand` and `/. { Cos[y/2] -> m, Sin[y/2] -> n, Cos[\[Theta]] -> p, 
  Sin[\[Theta]] -> q}`to get the following formula.

```
9 + Sqrt[5] - 5 m^4 + 3 Sqrt[5] m^4 + 30 m^2 n^2 - 
  18 Sqrt[5] m^2 n^2 - 5 n^4 + 3 Sqrt[5] n^4 - 40 Sqrt[2] m n p + 
  24 Sqrt[10] m n p + 40 Sqrt[2] m^3 n p - 24 Sqrt[10] m^3 n p - 
  40 Sqrt[2] m n^3 p + 24 Sqrt[10] m n^3 p - 20 m^2 p^2 + 
  12 Sqrt[5] m^2 p^2 + 20 n^2 p^2 - 12 Sqrt[5] n^2 p^2 + 20 m^2 q^2 - 
  12 Sqrt[5] m^2 q^2 - 20 n^2 q^2 + 12 Sqrt[5] n^2 q^2 == 0
```

it's easier for computer to solve this.

```
Solve[9 + Sqrt[5] - 5 m^4 + 3 Sqrt[5] m^4 + 30 m^2 n^2 - 
    18 Sqrt[5] m^2 n^2 - 5 n^4 + 3 Sqrt[5] n^4 - 40 Sqrt[2] m n p + 
    24 Sqrt[10] m n p + 40 Sqrt[2] m^3 n p - 24 Sqrt[10] m^3 n p - 
    40 Sqrt[2] m n^3 p + 24 Sqrt[10] m n^3 p - 20 m^2 p^2 + 
    12 Sqrt[5] m^2 p^2 + 20 n^2 p^2 - 12 Sqrt[5] n^2 p^2 + 
    20 m^2 q^2 - 12 Sqrt[5] m^2 q^2 - 20 n^2 q^2 + 
    12 Sqrt[5] n^2 q^2 == 0 && m^2 + n^2 == 1 && p^2 + q^2 == 1, {m, 
  n, p, q}, Reals]
```

the result is very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of @wuyudi, I'd like to develop it further.

After TrigExpand and substitution, reduce with respect to Sin,Cos conditions. Then do the reverse substitution. Look up the corresponding root expressions in red11.

```
te = 1/8 (-15 + Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y] + 
   4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 
   8 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[
     y]) == -3 // TrigExpand;

te2 = te /. {Cos[y/2] -> m, Sin[y/2] -> n, Cos[\[Theta]] -> p, 
Sin[\[Theta]] -> q};

rule = Reverse /@ {Cos[y/2] -> m, Sin[y/2] -> n, Cos[\[Theta]] -> p, 
  Sin[\[Theta]] -> q}

red = Reduce[{-1 <= m <= 1, -1 <= n <= 1, -1 <= p <= 1, -1 <= q <= 1, 
         m^2 + n^2 == 1, p^2 + q^2 == 1, te2}, Reals]

red11 = red /. rule // 
   Simplify[#, 0 < y < 2*Pi && 0 < \[Theta] < 2*Pi] &

red12 = red11 /. Root[__] -> root;

TraditionalForm[
   red12 //. 
   Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
   Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]